# Apex Test Class returning Null Value but appears to be working correctly?

Tags: apex, aggregateresult

My test code is retrieving "Null" instead of 1 when I test the below trigger. However, it's populating appropriately in the Salesforce instance itself.

The goal of this trigger is to relate an Agency Account to an Opportunity via a lookup relationship. Below is the trigger:

```
trigger totalopps on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {
    if(trigger.isinsert ||  trigger.isupdate)
        {
            List<Account> ta = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE RecordType.name = 'Agency/Brokerage']; 
            AggregateResult[] ar=[SELECT SUM(of_Opps__c) opps FROM Opportunity 
                                  WHERE Advisor_Broker__c =: ta];
            for (Opportunity o : trigger.new){ 
                double opps=
                        double.valueOf(ar[0].get('opps'))==null?0:(decimal)ar[0].get('opps');
            account a=new account(id=o.Advisor_Broker__c);
                        a.Total_Opportunities_by_Agency__c =
                            decimal.valueOf(opps);
                update a;
        }
    }   
}
```

And below is the test code:

```
@isTest

private class TotalOppsTest {
    static testMethod void TotalOpps(){

        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(Name = 'testOpp', 
                                              StageName = 'Closed Lost', 
                                              AccountId = '00111000021pNr0',
                                              Proposal_Date__c = date.newInstance(2020, 12, 24),
                                              CloseDate = date.newInstance(2020, 12, 25),
                                              Advisor_Broker__c = '00111000021pNYq');
        insert testOpp;
        
        system.assertEquals(1, testOpp.Advisor_Broker__r.Total_Opportunities_by_Agency__c, 'Opportunity Rollup Unsuccessful');                   
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting: `System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Opportunity Rollup Unsuccessful: Expected: 1, Actual: null`

I really appreciate any help anyone can give me - I'm sure it's something minor that I'm missing but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I see you have the account ID AND advisor broker id hard-coded. Do you have see all data true? In tests you should always create your own data and keep see all data false

Answer (score 1):

In order to see updated values after running a trigger, you need to query the records back from the database:

```
insert testOpp;
testOpp = [SELECT Advisor_Broker__r.Total_Opportunities_by_Agency__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :testOpp.Id];
system.assertEquals(1, testOpp.Advisor_Broker__r.Total_Opportunities_by_Agency__c, 'Opportunity Rollup Unsuccessful');
```

Please note that you need you also insert test accounts, rather than using existing Id values, or you'll still get the exception.

Also note, your trigger may have problems; your code does not account for opportunities on multiple accounts at once. Make sure you write a unit test that tests the correct behavior for at least two accounts in a single trigger transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. I got it to work with the direction you provided.